# Section name on the right hand sides (odd numbered)

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, double-sided

Here are the command lines that appear in the preamble of a book manuscript:

```
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{\nouppercase{\rightmark}}
\rhead{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
\markboth{\chaptername
\ \thechapter.\ \  #1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection.\ #1}}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\rm\thepage}
\fancyhead[LO]{\bfseries\rightmark}
\fancyhead[RE]{\bfseries\leftmark}
```

It is supposed to give me section on the right-hand sides and the chapter on the left hand sides. I get the chapter on both sides. Can anyone help? I tried to play around with the last two lines; no matter what I do (`\fancyhead[LO]{\bfseries\leftmark}` or  `\fancyhead[RE]{\bfseries\rightmark}`) I get the same. Can anyone help?

June 3: I am sorry to have bothered anyone. The problem was hidden in a file included further on. It works fine now.

Comment: Hi Bjarne and welcome to the site. Could you turn your code snippet into a full compilable `.tex` file, by adding `documentclass`, `\begin{document}` etc. Then I can paste it into my editor and see exactly the problem you're getting.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) As @JohnWickerson suggests, please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have activated the `oneside` option?

Comment: @JohnWickerson The question is about headers, not about the sections themselves. However, I got confused bu this at the first sight, too.

Comment: I just added `\documentclass{book}`, `\usepackage{fancyhdr}` and a sample document, and compiling it produced the headings that you want. I suspect the problem is something outside this set of commands, which makes an MWE somewhat a necessity. :)